# Injecting variables into Forms __construct function Zend 2

Tags: forms, zend-framework2

I am trying to prepopulate a form's drop down options via data stored statically in the module.config.php in Zend 2 and am running into a problem which entails:

1. I try to get the Servicemanager in the __construct() function but it is unavailable.
2. I move the element declarations to another function within the form class so I can pass variables into it but the view controller cannot find the elements.

I currently call the form via a Servicemanager Invokable. How can I pass these arrays into the form's __construct() function?

Here is the code:

```
class ILLForm extends Form
{
     public function __construct($fieldsetName, $campuses, $ILLTypes, $getFromOptions)
     {
        parent::__construct('create_ill');

        $this
             ->setAttribute('method', 'post')
             ->setHydrator(new ClassMethodsHydrator(false))
             ->setInputFilter(new InputFilter())
         ;


        $ill = new ILLFieldset('ill', $campuses, $ILLTypes, $getFromOptions);
        $ill->setName('ill')
            ->setOptions(array( 
               'use_as_base_fieldset' => true,
            ));

        $captcha = new Element\Captcha('captcha');
        $captchaAdapter = new Captcha\Dumb();
        $captchaAdapter->setWordlen(5);
        $captcha->setCaptcha($captchaAdapter)
                ->setLabelAttributes(array('class' => 'sq-form-question-title'))
                ->setAttribute('class', 'sq-form-field required')
                ->setLabel("* Captcha")
                ->setAttribute('title', 'Help to prevent SPAM');


        $submit = new Element\Submit('submit');
        $submit->setAttribute('value', 'Submit ILL')
                   ->setAttribute('class', 'sq-form-submit')
                   ->setAttribute('title', 'Submit ILL');

        $this->add($ill)
                ->add($captcha)
                ->add($submit);

     }



}
```

The Indexcontroller Factory that calls the Form:

```
class IndexControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $controllers)
    {
        $allServices = $controllers->getServiceLocator();
        $sm = $allServices->get('ServiceManager');
        $smConfig = $allServices->get('config');

        $campuses = $smConfig['campuses'];
        $illCategories = $smConfig['ILLCategories'];
        $getFromOptions = $smConfig['getFromOptions'];


        $controller = new IndexController();      
        $controller->setCampuses($campuses);
        $controller->setILLCategories($illCategories);
        $controller->setGetFromOptions($getFromOptions);
        $controller->setILLForm($sm->get('ILL-form'));
        $controller->setILLFormFilter($sm->get('ILL-form-filter'));
        //$controller->setParams($sm->get('params'));

        return $controller;
    }
}
```

and the relevant module.config.php excerpt:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'abstract_factories' => array(
        'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
        'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
    ),
    'invokables' => array(
        'ILL-form-filter'       => 'ILL\Form\ILLFormFilter',
        'ILL-form'              => 'ILL\Form\ILLForm',
    ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up taking the form out of the service manager invokables in module.config.php (removed line for 'ILL-form') and call it from the indexControllerFactory.php instead

```
$create_ill = new Form\ILLForm('create_ill', $campuses, $illCategories, $getFromOptions);

$controller->setILLForm($create_ill);
```

instead of

```
$controller->setILLForm($sm->get('ILL-form'));
```